# Django: Create object with ForeignKey from url

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am working on a Django project with two models linked by a `ForeignKey`.  The parent model, `Composition`, is linked to the child model, `NoteObject`, by the `id` of `Composition`.

in `models.py`

```
class Composition(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...

class NoteObject(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Once a composition is created, the user needs to be able to create `NoteObjects` that belong to that composition.  The notes are created with the following method:

in `views.py`

```
class NoteCreateView(CreateView):
    model = NoteObject
    template_name = 'entry.html'
    fields = ['duration', 'pitch', 'accidental', 'octave']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('compositions')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['notes'] = NoteObject.objects.filter(
            composition=self.kwargs['composition'])
        return super(NoteCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

The `get_context_data` method is there to display only the notes for the current composition.  The current composition comes from the `id` of the composition that is part of the url where `<composition>` is the id of the composition.

in `urls.py`

```
path('entry/<composition>/', views.NoteCreateView.as_view(), name='entry')
```

When I save a `NoteObject`, what do I need to do in order to set the value of the `ForeignKey` to be the value within `<composition>`?

in `models.py`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    composition_id = ????????
    self.composition_id = composition_id
    super(NoteObject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How do I get the value of `kwarg` in the `CreateView` to be the `ForeignKey` when the object is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this work, you need to override the dispatch function as well.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.composition = Composition.objects.values_list(
        'id').filter(pk=kwargs['composition'])
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.composition_id = self.composition
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

I used this solution and modified it slightly: [CreateView Set ForeignKey from Url Parameter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164147/createview-set-foreign-key-from-url-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by over-riding `form_valid` method as mentioned in [docs here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)

```
class NoteCreateView(CreateView):
    model = NoteObject
    template_name = 'entry.html'
    fields = ['duration', 'pitch', 'accidental', 'octave']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('compositions')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.composition = self.kwargs['composition']
        return super(NoteCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: No error is thrown when the form is submitted after adding your suggestion, but the objects are not getting added to the database.  When a composition object is created, the log shows a POST, the NoteObject is currently only showing a GET.  It is also staying on the current page and not redirecting to the success_url.